# How to join two tables with condition on their columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:
 
 
Table A :

```
id | key | price
```

Table B:

```
id | key | min | max
```

I want the rows from table **B** that **min** and **max** column contain the **price** column from table A. In other words price is greater than min and lower than max.
I used this code but didnt return the true result :

```
SELECT * FROM B INNER JOIN A ON A.key=B.key where A.price > B.min AND A.price < B.max;
```

Comment: Could you provide the example which actually went wrong?

Comment: Would you mind showing the sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this mysql query to fetch the results and make sure to set the price column to INT or FLOAT.

```html
SELECT 
    table1.id,table1.key,table1.price,
    table2.min,table2.max
FROM
    table1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
        AND (table1.price > table2.min
        AND table1.price < table2.max);
```

Comment: what is the difference between your query and mine ? Are they equal ?

Comment: Both are using almost same time in execution like 0.0006 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

try

> SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON B.key=A.key where A.price > B.min AND A.price < B.max;

**Left join** will return the values in the left table. In here  it's B

it's shown here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem . 
the **price** Column type was Varchar . I changed it to float and now the query return the true result.

Comment: You should probably use the [DECIMAL/NUMERIC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) data type rather than float, so you avoid [issues](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/uncategorized/sql-code-smells/#post-72422-using-float-or-real-data-types) with [imprecise](https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/) representations of numbers.